# azcopy and azure files

Tags: azure, azure-files, azcopy

Is there another way for authentication when using the command

`azcopy copy '<local-file-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<file-name><SAS-token>'`

and not using the a SAS token? Or put it in another way, can I save a SAS token somehow and read it when I write the above command? I am new to azure, and every time I upload/download files to/from azure files I need to get the SAS token from the azure portal. So what is the point of working in a CLI if I need to get the SAS token from a web browser.

Comment: What about OAuth authentication? Before azcopy copy, run azcopy login command?

Answer (score 1):

`azcopy` allows you to [Authenticate a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#authenticate-a-service-principal) or [Authenticate a user principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#authenticate-a-user-identity) using `azcopy login`.

See also:
[Choose how you'll provide authorization credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#choose-how-youll-provide-authorization-credentials)

---

**Update:**

You are right, az login is not support for file storage (only SAS is supported).

In this case you could generate your SAS Token using the Azure CLI:

[az storage file generate-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-generate-sas)

Comment: According with your last link, file storage type supports only SAS-token. I tried to run azcopy login and got the following error message: failed to get keyring during saving token, function not implemented